# what should i do fix my code? Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers, char

```
#include <iostream>
 bool isPalindrome(char* cstr)
 {
    char* front = cstr;
    char* back = cstr + strlen(cstr) - 1;
    while (front < back)
    {
        if (*front == *back)
        {
            back--;
            front++;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    char a[6];
    cin.getline(a, 7);
    cout << isPalindrome(a);    
    return 0;
 }
```

/* When I input , it happen */
/* Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted. */
/* When i change cin.getline(a,7) by cin.getline(a,6) it has no problem but can't cout the true answer */

Comment: Declare array of size 6, allow reading of up to 7 characters, probably also ignoring the existence of the null character.

Comment: but when i reading 6 characters it's can cout the true answers

Comment: Then make the size of a larger perhaps `char a[7];`

Comment: I realize this may be an assignment with many silly restrictions, but using `std::string` would make this very easy and much more bulletproof.

Comment: thank you but i only use char and i can rewrite from line (if(*front==*back))

Answer (score 0):

When a buffer (i.e. `char a[6]`) is declared (or any stack allocated variables for that matter) the compiler implements something called a stack cookie. It is a variable that can be verified. The whole purpose of it is to check whether something messy happened. The code will do something like this at the end:

```cpp
if(_stack_cookie != ...){
    __stack_chk_fail();
}
```

This is because the stack holds a lot of important information, such as the return pointer (which instruction to jump back to if we return from the function. If this was not checked, something stack smashing attacks would be possible).

The second issue is that you can only read `6-1` characters, because the last character will be `\0`, due to c-string formatting. Try `char a[7]`. Also watch out for `\0` in your palindrome code, so `back = cstr + strlen(cstr) - 2`